# C# - How to communicate between classes using interface with one property

Tags: c#, class, interface

Let's say I have an interface and two classes:

```
public interface Imyinterface
{
    string Text { get; set; }

}

public class Class1 : Imyinterface
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class Class2 : Imyinterface
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And the "problem" is communication between these two classes. I mean - I want Class2 to know when the string "Text" is changed in Class1 and what is its value.

Comment: Using an interface with a single property, this is going to be difficult. I assume you can update the interface... Probably the best approach would be to declare an event as part of the interface. [How to implement interface events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ak9w5846.aspx)

Comment: So you want any and all `Class2` instances to "know" when any `Class1` changes its `Text` and vice versa?

Comment: Can you clarify 'I want Class2 to know when the string "Text" is changed in Class1 and what is its value'. Do you want code in `Class2` to be triggered by a change to `Class1`, or simply want `Class2` to always have access to the latest value from `Class1`? Do you want it to work the other way too?

Comment: @crashmstr, Yes, this is what I want.

Comment: @Michal_Drwal: Are you sure that *all* `Class2` instances need to know about changes to *all* `Class1` instances? What is the actual use-case here? What relationship do those objects have?

Comment: The second class is actually a custom control for Silverlight. It has a TextBox in it. So I want to be able to get string from this "Control.xaml.cs" and put it to my MainPage class. But it has to be using interface.

Comment: Implementation of observer patter implementation from msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee850490(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Then add a `TextChanged` event to that interface, as spender already mentioned, and raise that event in the `Text` property setters. Then your `MainPage` instance can register an event handler on that Silverlight control and be notified of changes.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Would you be so kind and provide some code editing the code from my question? The problem is that I cannot call the instance of Class2 because both classes are "open" when the application starts. So how can I call the existing instance of Class2?

Comment: You will need to get a reference to that Silverlight control instance somehow. How to do that depends on how you've structured your application. Can you show the code (or XAML) where you create your main page and where you create that custom control?

Comment: I just put this        <SilverlightApplication1:PopupControl x:Name="popupControl2" Visibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,108,10,-63"/> to my main Grid. And the code for this control is in the same solution.

Comment: And that main grid is part of `MainPage.xaml`? Then you should be able to reference that UI control in `MainPage.xaml.cs` via the field `popupControl2`.

Comment: Yes, it is. How to reference to it via code? Can you give some example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Adding an event**

As has been mentioned in the comments by spender, you should add a text-changed event to your interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    // This event is raised whenever the value of Text is modified:
    event Action<IMyInterface, string> TextChanged;

    string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Classes that implement the interface should raise that event when their `Text` property changes:

```
public class Class1 : IMyInterface
{
    public event Action<IMyInterface, string> TextChanged;
    protected void RaiseTextChanged(string newValue)
    {
        var handler = TextChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, newValue);
    }

    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; RaiseTextChanged(value); }
    }
}
```

**Reacting to events**

Any code that is interested in changes to the `Text` property of an `IMyInterface` object can then register an event handler:

```
IMyInterface thing = new Class1();
thing.TextChanged += Thing_TextChanged;
...
void Thing_TextChanged(IMyInterface sender, string newValue)
{
    // Do something with the new value
}
```

**Your specific use-case**

In your particular case, you would add the following code to `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
// In MainPage's constructor, after the call to InitializeComponent:
popupControl2.TextChanged += PopupControl_TextChanged;

// A separate method in the MainPage class:
private void PopupControl_TextChanged(IMyInterface sender, string newValue)
{
    // Do what needs to be done with the next Text value here
}
```

Note that there is no need for both your Silverlight control and the main page class to implement that interface. From what I understand of your situation so far there is no need for an interface at all, but I suppose that depends on other requirements that you haven't told us about.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm sorry for the late answer but I was away for the weekend and I didn't have chance to do anything with the code.

Answer (score 4):

In general:

You have to use the observer pattern for that.

Make a subscribe method, every instance of Imyinterface needing to know about the text changes should call this method. Now in the set of 'Text' change the text and notify all subscribers.

See e.g. http://www.dofactory.com/net/observer-design-pattern

Comment: Implementing the observer pattern when events are first-class citizens of C# seems long-winded to me.

Comment: I know, but the instances of these classes are not connected (except that they share the same base class/interface.